# Is there a way to get IJulia to work with a poetry environment?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, python-poetry

I have a local Poetry `.venv` with Jupyter already installed. I am trying to get IJulia to work with this Jupyter installation as opposed to installing it through Conda. But I am not having much success.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$ poetry shell
$ julia
julia> ]
pkg> activate MyEnv
julia> ENV["JUPYTER"]=".venv/bin/jupyter"
julia> ]
pkg> add IJulia
julia> using IJulia
julia> notebook()
```

Then it still asks me if I want to install Jupyter with Conda. And I do not. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe try giving it the full absolute path in the ENV variable, instead of just the relative path?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that didn’t work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested on Ubuntu running on WSL2 and the following works for me.

1. Have `poetry` along `jupyter` installed
2. Check that `whereis python` resolves to poetry Python installation
3. Start Julia:

   ```
    $ poetry shell
    $ julia
   ```
4. Run the following code:

   ```
    using Pkg
    pyt = split(read(`whereis python`, String))[2]
    ENV["PYTHON"]=pyt;
    Pkg.build("PyCall")
    Pkg.build("IJulia")
   ```
5. Now you are done so you can do:

   ```
    julia> ENV["JUPYTER_TOKEN"]="mysecret";  # Jupyter password
    julia>  notebook(dir=".")
    [ Info: running `/home/ubuntu/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/ubuntu-zk_aSFMD-py3.10/bin/jupyter notebook`
   ```

Here is my installation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just launch the notebook separately from the command line.

You don't need the `notebook()` function in Julia to do it — that's only there as a convenience for people who installed Jupyter through IJulia, and will only work if you told IJulia where Jupyter was (via an environment variable) when IJulia was *built* (via `build IJulia` at the `pkg>` prompt).

(PyCall has nothing to do with this.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I am using a notebook via Quarto, though. Quarto automatically creates a notebook under-the-hood. So, I'm running into problems as a result.

Comment: That is right `Pkg.build("IJulia")` installs julia kernel in the jupyter environment. When you use an external Jupyter just make sure you are running the correct combination of Python, Jupyter and Julia (people tend to have more than one Python installation and than face PATH mixed-ups)